# Google App Script execute function when a user selects a cell in a range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'd like to run a function that requires authorization when a user clicks/selects a cell in a given range. A simple onSelectionChange(e) trigger doesn't work because of the authorization problem, and installable triggers don't include onSelectionChange apparently.

Is there another way to do so please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For functions that don't involve `ui`/`HtmlService`, Simple triggers can be used to run some functions that require authorization(say privileged functions) **by weakening security**:

- The flow: Trigger => onSelectionChange(no auth to fetch/execute privileged functions) => trigger custom functions(gain auth to fetch/no auth to execute privileged functions) => fetch/post => webapp(full auth to run privileged functions)
- This solution is inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52787692/),  which directly uses installable triggers and plain access tokens to authorize custom functions. This is not recommended from a security perspective.
- Although efforts have been taken to ensure security and privacy of user executing the following script, all attack vectors haven't been considered. The script might be vulnerable in a lot of areas, especially  given the lack of crypto module support in the platform. Use at your own risk, where alternate solutions are infeasible.
- In most cases, alternate solutions using menu/button/time triggers/installable triggers(which always runs under full auth) is preferred. **A similar flow can be achieved using onEdit installable trigger + checkbox**

To use the sample script, follow the following steps:

- [Set necessary scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes) in the manifest file. For the sample script,

  ```
   "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail"],
  ```
- [Publish a webapp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) for the explicit purpose of executing a function that requires authorization

  - Execute as "me"
  - Access: "Anyone"
- [Create a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating) with no roles/permissions for the explicit purpose of authorizing webapps from custom functions
- [Create a service account key](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys) and copy it to the `creds` object in the sample script.
- Share your project/spreadsheet with the service account (`client_email`)
- Install [Oauth2 library](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2#setup) to  create/sign jwt tokens for service account
- Create a `hiddenSheet` for setting a custom function, which will be set to set to A1 of this sheet `onSelectionChange`
- The following script sends email, when someone touches anything in your spreadsheet.

#### Sample script:

```
/**
 * Gets Oauth2 service based on service account with drive scope
 * Drive scope needed to access webapp with access:anyone
 * This does not grant access to the user's drive but the service
 *     account's drive, which will only contain the file shared with it
 */
function getService_() {
  const creds = {
    private_key: '[PRIVATE_KEY]',
    client_email: '[CLIENT_EMAIL]',
  };
  const PRIVATE_KEY = creds['private_key'];
  const CLIENT_EMAIL = creds['client_email'];
  return OAuth2.createService('GoogleDrive:')
    .setTokenUrl('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token')
    .setPrivateKey(PRIVATE_KEY)
    .setIssuer(CLIENT_EMAIL)
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
    .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');
}
/**
 * @returns {string} base64 encoded string of SHA_512 digest of random uuidstring
 */
const getRandHashKey_ = () =>
  Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(
    Utilities.computeDigest(
      Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_512,
      Utilities.getUuid() //type 4 advertised crypto secure
    )
  );

/**
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Events.SheetsOnSelectionChange} e
 */
const onSelectionChange = e => {
  const sCache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
  e.rangestr = e.range.getSheet().getName() + '!' + e.range.getA1Notation();
  const hashRandom = getRandHashKey_();
  sCache.put(hashRandom, JSON.stringify(e), 20);//expires in 20 seconds
  e.source
    .getSheetByName('hiddenSheet')
    .getRange('A1')
    .setValue(`=CALLWEBAPP("${hashRandom}")`);
};
/**
 * Calls published webapp(Access:Anyone) with service account token
 * @customfunction
 * @returns void
 */
const callwebapp = randomHash => {
  const webAppScriptId = '[SCRIPT_ID]';
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    `https://script.google.com/macros/s/${webAppScriptId}/exec`,
    {
      method: 'post',
      payload: { e: randomHash },
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${getService_().getAccessToken()}` },
    }
  );
};

/**
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Events.AppsScriptHttpRequestEvent} e
 */
const doPost = e => {
  const hashRandom = e.parameter.e;
  const sCache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
  const encodedSelectionEvent = sCache.get(hashRandom);
  if (encodedSelectionEvent) {
    const selectionEvent = JSON.parse(encodedSelectionEvent);
    MailApp.sendEmail(
      '[EMAIL_TO_SEND_NOTIFICATION_TO]',
      'Someone touched your spreadsheet',
      `Wanna take a look? ${selectionEvent.rangestr} was touched without your permission`
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up adding a column with the value "Clear to run function" on each row, with a simple onEdit(e) that triggers my function if one value in this column in different from "Clear to run function".

From a UX perspective, it means clearing a cell to run the function - not ideal, but it works.

Comment: A checkbox would be more ideal