Using setNote in custom function causes permissions error
I'm using Apps Script to make a custom function that sets the note of a specific cell in a spreadsheet, but I'm getting the error "Exception: You do not have permission to call setNote," even though the cell that's being targeted is the same cell that's calling the function. My code is:
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 

function setCellNote(targRow, targCol, text, display) { 
  var cell = sh.getRange(targRow, targCol);
  cell.setNote(text); 
  return display;
}

and the call in the sheet is in cell A2 as =setCellNote(ROW(A2),COLUMN(A2),"test", "done")
I've tried using A1 notation, but I had to have the cell reference in quotes (meaning =setCellNote("A2"),...), and I need this to work across many cells, so the actual cell reference needs to automatically change as I copy the formula across many cells.
I've seen people have issues where they try to edit a cell that's not in the range being used for their function, but I'm getting this error when trying to use setNote on the same cell that's calling the function.

It doesn't matter if you're using the same cell. If set* methods  throw an error, there's nothing you can do about it(except maybe use a hack https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63634396/google-app-script-execute-function-when-a-user-selects-a-cell-in-a-range/63655160#63655160  ). To be clear, custom functions are designed to do what inbuilt functions are designed to do. You don't  expect a function like =SUM() to set a note. Right?
